# Logical operators - 'or' vs. '||' (double pipe) in PHP

Tags: php, logical-operators

I've always used `||` (double pipe) for `if (($a == $b) || ($a == $c)) { }` and `or` for `do_this() or do_that();`.

Why not `if (($a == $b) or ($a == $c)) { }` or `do_this() || do_that();`?

Is there a reason to use any of these two logical operators or it is just a personal preference?

The same applies for `&&` vs. `and`, of which I only use `&&`.

Comment: About the duplicate: The question is very similar, is true, but not exactly the same, and unfortunately it is difficult to find a question when you search only for "|| vs OR", that is the reason why i used "Double pipe" in the title.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The "spelled out" operators `and` and `or` have lower precedence, even lower than assignment, so you may use them to avoid having to write parentheses in so many places. For example:

`$d=$a||$b and $c` is equivalent to `($d=$a||$b) && $c`

They are also more readable in many contexts.

Comment: In the concrete case of `if ($a || $b) { ... }` is just the preference to use `||` or `or`?

Comment: Depends on what $a and $b are. If they are variables, readability is the only difference. If they are complex expressions the difference in precedence may play a role.

Answer (score 9):

The two different versions operate at different precedences:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php