# how to get empty fields from db

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I want to extract empty fields from db but in return this code not working

```
function check_empty_fields($user_last_ad_id){
    $query = $this->db->query(
      "SELECT * FROM ad
      WHERE ad_user_id = ?
      ORDER BY id
      DESC LIMIT 1",
      $user_last_ad_id)->result_array()[0];

      foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value) or strlen($value) == 0 or $value == 0) {
          $empty_field[] = $key;
        }
      }

      return $empty_field;
  }
```

**all fields** this is my all db table fields and I want to filter empty and "0" fields

```
Array
(
    [id] => 283
    [ad_user_id] => 3
    [ad_name] => Asus n555
    [ad_category] => 1
    [ad_title] => 3
    [ad_message_id] => 0
    [ad_second_message_id] => 0
    [ad_price] => 0
    [ad_photo_file_id] => 0
    [ad_explanation] => 
    [ad_link] => 
    [ad_date] => 0000-00-00
    [ad_cast_premition] => 0
)
```

**output:** this is the output that the function returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => ad_name
    [1] => ad_message_id
    [2] => ad_second_message_id
    [3] => ad_price
    [4] => ad_explanation
    [5] => ad_link
    [6] => ad_date
    [7] => ad_cast_premition
)
```

as you see it didn't filter empty or "0" fields, 
How can I do that

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: It's possible that your 0 is string datatype and not number, add this to your if statement : `or $value == '0'`

Comment: @ThomasG PHP is loosely typed, so `'0' == 0` is true.

Comment: You could possibly use something like `array_diff($query , array_filter($query))` instead of looping though. I haven't tried it, I'm a little unsure if it will filter your `ad_date` properly to your request, but the rest should be filtered away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (empty($value) or strlen($value) == 0 or $value == 0) {
```

should be

```
if (empty($value) || strlen($value) == 0 || value == 0) {
```

or rather this will work as well

```
if (!$value) {
```

Comment: There isn't any deference between `||` and `or` according to [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: They have different precedence though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17710924/logical-operators-or-vs-double-pipe-in-php.

Comment: @MasoudTavakkoli Why get into defining specific cases when just `if(!$value)` will work. It will take care of 0, '0', null, false, '', [], etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (empty($value) or strlen($value) == 0 or $value == 0)
```

should be

```
if (empty($value) or $value === 0)
//  empty string / strictly equals to ZERO
```

with 3 equal sign, which means "strictly"